# Find the limit of the trignometric function?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

So I went through all the problems fairly easily until I got to 44-47.

[image]

I tried working them out and got:
44) 15
46) 1
The answers for 45 (1/2) and 47 (-root2) were in the back of the book but I do not understand how to get them... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Edit) Okay so I understand it now, but just a quick question on 47... 
When I worked it out I got to the answer of -2/(root2), but the answer is just -root2... How does it simplify like that? (I worked it out by making tan = sin/cos instead of doing the conjugate of tan if that makes any difference)

Comment: I have deleted my moronic comment and enrolled myself in basic arithmetic class ;)

Comment: @barrycarter That happens to absolutely everyone.

Comment: re edit: note that
$$-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}^2}{\sqrt{2}}=-\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**44** Did you get it? Write it as $15\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x}\frac{\sin(5x)}{5x}$ if you didn't.

**45** Divide numerator and denominator by $\theta$. You get $\frac{\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}}{1+\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}}$

**46** Is actually $0$. Write it as $x\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$ and notice that $\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}\to1$.

**47** Write it as $-\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\frac{1-\tan(x)}{1-\tan(x)}$

**48** Write it as $\frac{1}{x+2}\frac{\sin(x-1)}{x-1}$.

Comment: Not going to let him do anything? Be nice!

Comment: @AaronMaroja He has always the choice of not reading everything. Me writing everything here doesn't limit that choice in any way. On the other hand it provides the opportunity of finding a hint if he gets stuck. Lots of people in this website confuse the differences a website has with a classroom.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I get it now. I already knew the rules beforehand but I was just having problems splitting up the function into the different parts.

Comment: @Pp.. Still spoiling the fun. But I guess you have a point. Although we both know that's not going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use l'Hôpital's rule. In calculus, l'Hôpital's rule  uses derivatives to help evaluate limits involving indeterminate forms. For instance for (44) your limit is the same of that of a new function where you replace the numerator by its derivative and the denominator by its derivative. For the (44) you 've to differentiate twice.